# Razor, .Net core: Optional field being created as object with empty value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am creating a checkout form using razor and asp.net core 3.1.
After the checkout form is submitted, the `order` object is also created automatically. And the `telephone` field, which supposes to be optional, is also being created as an object with `null` values like below (if the user leave the input field blank and submits the form).

[image]

My simplified model looks like this

```
 public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderStock = new HashSet<OrderStock>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Telephone Telephone { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderStock> OrderStock { get; set; }
}
```

My razor page looks something like this:

```
 <form id="CheckOut" asp-controller="CheckOut" asp-action="CreateOrder" method="post">
<div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
    <label asp-for="Address.Street">Street <span>*</span></label>
    <input asp-for="Address.Street" type="text" class="form-control mb-3" maxlength="50" />
</div>
...
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <label asp-for="Telephone.TelephoneNumber">Phone No</label>
    <input asp-for="Telephone.TelephoneNumber" type="number" class="form-control" min="0" maxlength="20"/>
</div>
<div class="col-12 mb-4">
    <label asp-for="Email.EmailAddress">Email Address <span>*</span></label>
    <input asp-for="Email.EmailAddress" type="email" class="form-control" maxlength="30"/>
</div>
```

So I have to get rid of this `telephone`-object being created, to make the database *happy*, because it's is trying to save an empty record into `telephone` table in my db.
The first solution, that I could think of is, using `if`-statement in my controller like this.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.Telephone.TelephoneNumber))
{
   order.Telephone = null;
}
```

But that is clearly not the best solution to avoid this. It's there any better way to handle this?

Comment: Don't use your entity objects as your view models. Create view models only with the properties you need and then map them to entity objects. Using entity/data models in this fashion can be dangerous and subject to potential over-posting

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks for your advice. I will replace those entities with my own view models. Maybe it will solve my problem as well.

Comment: It will so long as your view models only contain the properties that you actually want/need

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 So I have replaced my entities models with my view models for the GUI and use `automapper` for mapping. But the problem still remains. My idea was that, to check within `Order`-object if the `TelephoneNumber` is `null` or not. Then return null if user didn't input any `telNr`. Something like this

`public TelViewModel TelViewModel { get { return TelViewModel.TelNr == null ? null : TelViewModel; } set { TelViewModel = value; } }`

But my application crashes for no reason, when I was trying to open my form.